# Convert avi video file to mpeg format using C#

Tags: c#, .net, converters, multimedia

I'm building a .NET winforms application and I need to convert avi video format to mpeg video format. How can I do this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This sounds suspiciously like a "give the the code" question. There are plenty of AVI to MPEG converters already in existence, so the first question would be why you need to roll your own. The second question would be, "what have you already tried?". If the answer is "nothing" you will not get much help here.

Comment: Do you start from a scratch or did you tried something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Platform `FFmpeg` in order to convert your files

Link : http://www.ffmpeg.org/

Answer (score 1):

One of the major problems that we faced when developing our application is the ability to convert different video formats (AVI, OGG, MP4, etc.) to DVD format. We ended up using a third-party toolkit named leadtools. I think they have mpeg DirectShow filters that might help you to fulfill your requirements. You can find more information here:
http://leadtools.com/sdk/multimedia/conversion.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can use third party component which you call from c#....The mostly used component for the conversion is [FFmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) .

`FFmpeg` includes libavcodec - the leading audio/video codec library.